# Диагональный вывод

Tags: python, рекурсия

Как сделать это задание? Через два цикла for получается вывод лесенкой...[image]

Comment: 1. Непонятно, а как надо? Что вы имеете ввиду под словом "диагональный вывод"? 2. Если вам надо просто более "крутой" вывод лестницей - делайте при выводе отступ не 2 позиции, а 4. Или 8. Столько, сколько удовлетворяет вашему понятию "диагональности".

Comment: Получается такая вещь: https://pp.userapi.com/c849336/v849336488/145382/LBHyNwircgk.jpg

Comment: Тем более, вроде как нужно, чтобы печать выводилась посредством обращения к функции factorial(), то есть в In вбиваю factorial(4) и получается такой вывод, как на картинке в самом вопросе.

Comment: @kyufleck Мы должны угадать, какой ваш код это производит? Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создаёте глобальную переменную, например, `initial_n` со значением `None`
2. Внутри функции `factorial`  (до вызова следующей итерации рекурсии) пишите, что если `initial_n is None` то записываем в `initial_n` текущий аргумент функции `factorial`
3. Где-то после этого, но тоже до вызова следующей итерации, выводите отладочную информацию с отступом кратным `(initial_n - текущий_аргумент_функции)`
4. Если текущий аргумент функции - 0, то обратно делаем `initial_n = None`